# Plane is not appearing as blue in render

Tags: rendering, materials

As a beginner I seem to be having a lot of trouble.  Here are some other questions I have asked along the way but found that I have to start again.

This time, my plane is not appearing.  It appears in Object mode, it only appears to be the correct colour in Material view.

Any solutions? I am sure it's simple.

My file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/osbdhl6cv9iuprp/FLAG_WORKING_SO_FAR.blend?dl=0).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some reason your object has shadow catcher and dupli faces selected. Both prevent it being displayed in render view.

[image]

Comment: Where Dupli Faces is a way of duplicating another object onto the faces of your object(via parenting) and Shadow Catcher will hide the mesh except for any shadows that fall onto it.

Comment: @rob - thanks so much for your help today!